# How to set a char inside a struct in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, malloc

How do I allocate memory for a char variable (not a char pointer) inside a struct?
(Variable names are in portuguese, sorry if it's kinda confusing)

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct node{
    char rotulo[10], instrucao[1][2][10], flag;
    int simplificado;

    struct node *referencias[2];
    struct node **antecessores;
    int nrAntecessores;

    struct node *ant;
    struct node *prox;
} Estado;
```

And this is function `insere()` that sets values read from an input file in a new node:

```
void Insere(char *rotulo, char instrucao[][2][10], int qtdInstrucao, char flag){
    int i,j;
    Estado *NovoEstado;
    NovoEstado = (Estado*)malloc(sizeof(Estado));
    NovoEstado->prox = NULL;
    NovoEstado->ant = P->ult;
    strcpy(NovoEstado->rotulo, rotulo);
    NovoEstado->flag = flag;
    NovoEstado->antecessores = NULL;
    NovoEstado->nrAntecessores = 0;
    NovoEstado->simplificado = 0;

    for(i=0;i<qtdInstrucao;i++){
        realloc(NovoEstado->instrucao, i+1*sizeof(char[2][10]));
        strcpy(NovoEstado->instrucao[i][0], instrucao[i][0]);
        strcpy(NovoEstado->instrucao[i][1], instrucao[i][1]);
    }
}
```

This `NovoEstado->flag = flag;` isn't working...
Right after I set it, if I print `NovoEstado->flag` i get the right value, but if I put it after that `for` by the end of the function, when I print `NovoEstado->flag` I get the first char of NovoEstado->rotulo...
The same happens when I try to print `flag` in `main()`...

I figure that's because I'm not properly allocating memory space to `flag` in `Insere()`, is that right? And how do I fix it?

I'm pretty sure it's an awful easy question, and that I possibily knew this once, but I forgot and can't find it anywhere... So any help would be very appreciated

**EDIT**

Following ocdecio's tip I created a pointer to an two-dimensional array, in order to have a dinamic 3 dimensional array.
My goal is to have a "table" like this:

```
  10 chars | 10 chars  
|__________|__________|
|__________|__________|
|__________|__________|
```

Where the number of lines is dinamic, but it's always an array of 2 strings of 10 chars.

So now this is what I'm doing in main:

```
    char estado[127], rotulo[10], strInstrucoes[117], *conjunto = calloc(21, sizeof(char)), flag;
    char (*instrucao)[2][10];

    FILE * entrada;
    Automato *Aut = (Automato*)malloc(sizeof(Automato));

    if((entrada = fopen(argv[1], "r")) != NULL){
        CriaAutomato(Aut);
        while(fgets(estado, 127, entrada)){
            flag = 0;
            sscanf(estado,"%[^:]: %[^;]; %c", rotulo, strInstrucoes, &flag);
            instrucao = calloc(1, sizeof(char[2][10]));
            conjunto = strtok(strInstrucoes,"() ");
            for(i = 0; conjunto != NULL; i++){
                realloc(instrucao, i+1*sizeof(char[2][10]));
                sscanf(conjunto,"%[^,],%s", instrucao[i][0], instrucao[i][1]);
                printf("%s || %d\n", instrucao[i][1], i);
                conjunto = strtok(NULL, "() ");
            }
            Insere(Aut, rotulo, instrucao, i, flag);
            free(instrucao);
        }
        fclose(entrada);
```

But this isn't working...
This is the input read from file

```
adsasdfg2: (abc,123) (def,456) (ghi,789);
```

but even before I call `Insere` I'm not assigning the right values to `instrucao` the way I want, as this is the output of that `printf`

```
123
454
789
```

instead of what I'm aiming for

```
123
456
789
```

What's wrong?

(before someone asks, this is **part** of a homework, but not **the** homework. My task is to make a Deterministic Finite Automata minimizer, this is just a bug I'm getting related to data input)

Thanks a whole lot

Comment: Nope, it's not that. When you do a malloc(sizeof(Estado)) you are allocating space for flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is likely to be in this line:

```
realloc(NovoEstado->instrucao, i+1*sizeof(char[2][10]));
```

There is no need to allocate anything inside your structure because the field `instrucao` is statically defined by the statement `instrucao[1][2][10]`, it is not a dynamically allocated structure.

Comment: So if I rewrite `instrucao` as a dinamically allocated struct (as I need it to be) it should work?

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is the problem:

```
realloc(NovoEstado->instrucao, i+1*sizeof(char[2][10]));
```

In the structure the instrucao is defined as a chunk of continuous memory but you are now allocating a memory and assigning the pointer.

Try commenting it out, you don't need to allocate memory for that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to allocate flag. It's a char defined inside the struct (as oppose to a pointer).

Your error is caused by overwriting flag's contents inside the struct during the for loop where you write to `NovoEstado->instrucao` (i.e. its a memory scribble or overwrite).

Update: as @ocdecio points out, you do not need to realloc inside the loop, as `instrucao` is also statically allocated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the intent of the code, but it's certainly illegal to do the following:

realloc(NovoEstado->instrucao, i+1*sizeof(char[2][10]));

Basically, the containing structure was allocated using malloc, but the inner-member in question is a statically defined array and it can't be rellocated using the heap (because the heap manager tracks only the malloced pointer to node).

typedef struct node{    char rotulo[10], **instrucao[1][2][10],** flag;

If you wish to resize for *instrucao* dynamically, you must define it as a pointer type and allocate memory for it separately.